# "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Int'" error?

Tags: swift

```
func decideLeapYear(year: Int) -> Bool{
var lyear: Bool = false
  if(year<1582){
    if(((year/4)%1)==0){
        lyear = true
    }
  }
  else if(year>=1582)
  {
    if(((year%4)==0) || (year%400==0) && ((year%100)!=0)){
      lyear = true
    }
  }

return lyear
}
```

At the end of the `if` statement in the `else if` statement, Xcode throws this error:

> Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Int'

when it reaches the statement:

```
((year%100)!=0))
```

Can anyone explain why and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the compiler thinks that `((year%100)!=0))` is actually `((year%100)! = 0))` and so tries to unwrap `(year%100)!`.

The solution is to add a space before `!=`:

```
func decideLeapYear(year: Int) -> Bool{
    var lyear: Bool = false
    if(year<1582){
        if(((year/4)%1)==0){
            lyear = true
        }
    }

    else if(year>=1582)
    {
        if(((year%4)==0) || (year%400==0) && ((year%100) != 0)) {
            lyear = true
        }
    }

    return lyear
}
```

Also, just a note: you don't need to enclose conditions in brackets, and space characters in code don't cost anything. So I suggest adding some air to your code like this:

```
func decideLeapYear(year: Int) -> Bool {
    if year < 1582 {
        if (year / 4) % 1 == 0 {
            return true
        }
    } else if year >= 1582 {
        if year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

*I've also removed the bool variable to make the code even cleaner.*

Comment: Note that this returns `true` for every multiple of 4 (but that problem existed already in the original code).

Comment: Also, the `else if` condition is redundant: If control flow doesn't enter the first first `if`, the year *must* be greater than or equal to 1582.

Comment: This method returns true for 1800, 1900 , 2100, 2200, 2300, 2500 and so on

Comment: This method also returns true for any year before 1582